# Fill in subsequent null values based on the value from the first row in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a table shown as below

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ruk1h.png)

The first row of column G (pesudo_payment) is generated from column C (balance) , f(payment), using formula: g=c*(1+e)-f
however, starting from the second row, column G is based on the previous value of column G, which should be: g3=g2(1+e3)-f3

I tried to "rank" first and take rank=1 to calculate the first row of each group.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import rank

window = Window.partitionBy(df['loan_id']).orderBy(df['date'])

df_new=df.select('*', rank().over(window).alias('rank'))
df_new=df_new.withColumn('col_g',
        F.when(F.col('rank')=='1',F.col('balance')*(1+F.col('rate'))-
        F.col('payment'))
       )
```

I tried using lag function for rank not equals to 1 but wouldn't work because NA values is still NA after lag.

How should I write this code in pyspark?

Comment: The number of times the same id appears in your table is 0-5(total=6) times. Is this number constant for all of your different ids? If yes, then I have a solution for you.

Comment: if you can confirm your ids appear the same amount of times, i can give you solution..